# How to display two Label controls side by side in a panel that is docked top?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Panel` object called `dockTop`.  I add two labels to said `Panel`.  I want the labels to to flow from left to right.  This is akin to what one expect's out of a `div` with css set to `float: left`...only this is winforms.

I have

```
   //I want DockStyle.Left, but that causes both controls to be of height, width = 0,0
   dockTop.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "one", Dock = DockStyle.Top });
   dockTop.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "two", Dock = DockStyle.Top });
```

Dock Top works fine, but that's not what I want.  How can I display the labels next to eachother from left to right within a Panel that is set to Dock Top?

Comment: @LarsTech - I'm going with your TableLayoutPanel suggestion.  That works.

Comment: Hmm, no, for an auto-sizing control like Label you'll want a FlowLayoutPanel to get the side-by-side.

Comment: @HansPassant - Ill give the flowlayout a go on Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to place them yourself by setting the location. If need be, set the Anchor properties appropriately. Alternatively, you could use a TableLayoutPanel instead of the Panel

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set `Dock` to `DockStyle.Top` and `DockStyle.Left`

```
   dockTop.Controls.Add(new Label {Text = "one", Dock = DockStyle.Top | DockStyle.Left });
   dockTop.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "two", Dock = DockStyle.Top | DockStyle.Left });
```

[image]

or you could use `AutoSize` with `DockStyle.Left`

```
   dockTop.Controls.Add(new Label {Text = "one", Dock = DockStyle.Left, AutoSize=true });
   dockTop.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "two", Dock =  DockStyle.Left, AutoSize = true});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i use `Resize` event to achieve this task. i hope it will helps you.

```
static class Program
{
    static Label label1;
    static Label label2;
    static Form form1;
    static Rectangle rectForm;
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        form1 = new Form();
        rectForm = form1.ClientRectangle;
        Panel dockTopPanel = new Panel {Height = 100, Dock = DockStyle.Top, BackColor = Color.White };
        label1 = new Label { Text = "Label1", Dock = DockStyle.Left, BackColor = Color.Red, Width = rectForm.Width / 2 };
        label2 = new Label { Text = "Label2", Dock = DockStyle.Right, BackColor = Color.Blue, Width = rectForm.Width / 2 };
         label2.BringToFront();
        Control[] labels= {label1, label2};
        dockTopPanel.Controls.AddRange(labels);
        form1.Controls.Add(dockTopPanel);
        form1.Resize += new EventHandler(form1_Resize);
        Application.Run(form1);
    }

    static void form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rectForm = form1.ClientRectangle;
        label1.Width = (rectForm.Width / 2) + 1;
        label2.Width = (rectForm.Width / 2) + 1;
    }
}
```